# Phoenix: Supervisor ignores name, new processes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got an `application.ex` that looks like this:

```
defmodule Qtrain.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    children = [
      supervisor(QtrainWeb.Endpoint, [], name: Qtrain.Supervisor),
      supervisor(Qtrain.Requests, [], name: Qtrain.Requests)
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    QtrainWeb.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

And a `requests.ex` that looks like this:

```
defmodule Qtrain.Requests do
  use GenServer
  alias Qtrain.Requests.Document

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_work()
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:work, state) do
    Document.start_link %{id: :one}
    schedule_work()
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp schedule_work() do
    Process.send_after(self(), :work, 1 * 1000)
  end
end
```

When I start my app and run `:observer.start` I can see the task with a `:one` key as expected, but there are two things wrong. One, the parent supervisor has no name despite me specifying one, and two, subsequent processes added in `iex -S mix` like so:

```
Qtrain.Requests.Document.start_link %{id: :dammit}
```

Don't result in processes being added beneath the `pid`.

[image: :observer.start]

But, they do show up in the processes tab:

[image: proc]

Any reason why I can't name that supervisor? And why new processes don't appear under it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Passing the `name` options to `Supervisor.Spec.supervisor/3` has no effect in both cases (check that `observer` shows `Endpoint` for the endpoint, while `name` is set to `Supervisor`.) In fact, there is even [no option `name` understood](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html#module-supervisor-and-worker-options). You should set the name in the call to subsequent `GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)` required to make it shown in `observer`.
2. `Whatever.start_link` does not make a started process to be a part of the supervision tree. You should explicitly set it to be a child of the respective supervisor with [`Supervisor.start_child/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_child/2) (when the parent is a supervisor, not your case,) or just call `Document.start_link` from within the respective `GenServer` process, [since](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#start_link/3)

> `start_link` starts a `GenServer` process **linked to the current process**.

Example:

```
defmodule Qtrain.Requests do

  # interface
  def document!(id) do
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:document, id})
  end

  def handle_call({:document, id}, _from, state) do
    Qtrain.Requests.Document.start_link %{id: id}
  end

  ...
end
```

And now:

```
Qtrain.Requests.document! :damnit
```

would make a `Document` a part of the supervision tree, since it’ll be linked to the `Requests` process. When you have just started it from the console, it was linked to `mix` process.

Comment: Well I couldn’t have asked for a more thorough answer. Thank you! I’m moving a sidekiq app from Rails and trying my luck at OTP.

Comment: Good luck then! I personally found it to be very straightforward and, frankly, exciting, to move from ruby to elixir due to many things (specifically, OTP.)